# Need help understanding Cardview item click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Firstly, I have to tell you that I have very limited experience with Android programming. Basically, I picked up a book and tried self teaching with only limited success.  :( 
In short, I want to be able to open a second activity with the details of a cardview item when clicked

I have searched the net extensively to find information, or a tutorial on selecting a single item from a recyclerview/cardview layout but haven't found anything I can make work.

Currently, I have an onclick in my cardview xml (android:onClick="displaycard") which will run the displaycard() method in the java class.

This works fine, but only takes me to the generic individual item activity.  I can search the database by itemID once in the activity using a search field and button, but I would like to populate the activity via the cardview button click

This is the cardview with the onclick item in it...

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/CardItem"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#0066ff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="displaycard"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="30dp"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
```

The following is the method that opens the generic activity. Generic meaning the activity without the database content populated

```
public void displaycard(View view) {
  Intent defView = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,DisplayIndividual.class);
// this is where i pass the search parameters to DisplayIndividual.java     (search parameter is Tk-128, putExtra passes it to the activity)
    // I want to be able to pass the ID of the card that was clicked
    String strSearch = "Tk-128";
    defView.putExtra("STRING_2_Search", strSearch);
    startActivity(defView);
    }
```

Each cardview has a textview with the id I would like to search for.  I want to pass 'android:id="@+id/ConfinedSpaceID"' using putExtra into the activity that is opened. In the example above,  I would like to replace the value "Tk-128" with the value of the android:id="@+id/ConfinedSpaceID" of the clicked cardview item.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/ConfinedSpaceID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:text="Confined Space ID"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Not sure if I have explained myself clearly...  hope I have given enough information to replicate the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your cardview has only one TextView, or if your value is always on the first TextView, this should work:

```
public void displaycard(CardView view) {
        String strSearch;
        for(int i=0;i<view.getChildCount();i++){
            View maybeTextView = view.getChildAt(i);
            if(maybeTextView instanceof TextView){
                strSearch=((TextView)maybeTextView).getText().toString();
                break;
            }

        }
        Intent defView = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,DisplayIndividual.class);

        defView.putExtra("STRING_2_Search", strSearch);
        startActivity(defView);
    }
```

What it does, is it loops through all the child views on the CardView, and when it finds a TextView, it saves it's value on a variable, which you can then use to pass to your intent as you did before.
Note that I changed the argument of the fuction from public void displaycard(View view) to public void displaycard(CardView view)

Comment: Thank you jokogarcia.    When I use your code the following line gives me an error:  
    defView.putExtra("STRING_2_Search", strSearch);
    startActivity(defView);

strSearch gives me the error "Variable strSearch might not have been initialized"  :(

Comment: Hello again jokogarcia…   I moved the String strSearch; variable outside the method and that got rid of the error message, but now, instead of opening the activity, it takes me back to my main activity and closes the program/app

Comment: One last question...   would I need to add my code to the Recyclerview class, or to the individual item cardview class?

Comment: jokogarcia...   thank you for your help.   Although it didn't solve my problem, it did give me direction on where to look and what to look for.  I now have an onclick listener in the adapter class that gets the information i need and passes it to a Toast.  Now I just have to figure out how to open an activity from within an adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved -  All of your input has taught me about getContext().  This of course is what I needed to start an activity from within a java class.  Thank you all